# How to Dynamically Re-size The Length of btn.group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to attach a `.btn-group` under a Bootstrap `carousel slide`.As you can see I have group of `. btn  btn-inverse` in the `.btn-group`.Now what I would like to do is pulling the first three`. btn  btn-inverse` to the LEFT of div `well span9` and  puuling last two `. btn  btn-inverse` to the RIGHT of the  div `well span9`.So the `dyno` class must be in dynamic format to be re-sized based on the .well size. Please take alook at uploaded image as well.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well span9">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
           <img src="****" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <img src="****" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <img src="*****" alt="" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
     <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group hidden-phone">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-stop"></i></a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-play"></i></a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-pause"></i></a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse dyno">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-resize-full"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-fullscreen"></i></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can't you `pull-right` and `pull-left` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/S8EDL/)

Notice that I am using all stock bootstrap code with the `pull-right` and `pull-left`.

Comment: Great! Thanks sulfureous!